# How can I register a specific singleton instance with Caliburn Micro's Simple Container?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I've registered a type in Caliburn Micro using it's Simple Container as a singleton.

```
_container.Singleton<MyType>("MyType");
```

Now I've realized I need to pass in some specific constructor parameters, so I created an instance of the registered class, configured it, then tried to use RegisterSingleton. And realized it doesn't seem to let me pass a specific instance. I've looked at the [docs](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Simple%20IoC%20Container/) and don't quite understand how this was supposed to work.

How can I get it to use this specific instance for the singleton?

Answer (score 4):

Call `SimpleContainer.RegisterInstance` with the service type, key and implementation.

For example:

```
_container.RegisterInstance(typeof(MyType), "MyType", new MyType());
```

The simple container is documented [here](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/simple-container).

Comment: you don't specifically have to give the instance type a name e.g. middle param in the above registration, it can be a empty string or null, otherwise you will have to use that key to get it.

Comment: The question includes the key, hence the reason I placed it in my answer.

Comment: my bad :), Just saw it